# gdi32 install fonts for session with non latin names

Tags: powershell, winapi, unicode

I am trying to install fonts in a temporary manner for the current session via a PowerShell script.

My current script is provided below, but the problem is that if the font is called "somelatin_font.ttf" it will work fine, but if the font has some non Latin characters (example Japanese) in its name, it will fail to install

```
$dir="fonts"

$signature = @'
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
 public static extern int AddFontResource(string lpszFilename);
'@

$type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature `
    -Name FontUtils -Namespace AddFontResource `
    -Using System.Text -PassThru

foreach($font in  (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir -Recurse  | Where-Object {$_.extension -in ".ttf", ".otf"}) ) {   
    $ffn= $font.FullName
    echo "loading($ffn)" >> file.txt
    $type::AddFontResource($font)
}
```

I also tried adding `CharSet = CharSet.Auto` or `unicode` but neither of them worked:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
```

The error I get when I add this:

> Add-Type : Cannot add type. The type name 'AddFontResource.FontUtils' already exists.

Does anyone have an idea on how to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you made sure to save your script file in a Unicode format (preferably UTF16LE or UTF8)?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir would that matter if I am never handling the string manually? my script itself does not contain any utf8. The names are caught by the for loop and passed directly to `addfontresource` 
Also the names printed in file.txt are correct and not replaced by some ??? so the variable is storing the correct name correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For full Unicode support, you must qualify your P/Invoke declaration with `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode`, which ensures that the *Unicode* version of the WinAPI function, i.e. [`AddFontResourceW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourcew), is (implicitly) referenced:

```bash
$signature = @'
  [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
  public static extern int AddFontResource(string lpszFilename);
'@

$type =
  Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature `
    -Name FontUtils -Namespace AddFontResource `
    -Using System.Text -PassThru
```

**Note**:

- If you get error message `The type name 'AddFontResource.FontUtils' already exists.`, *start a new session*, because that implies that a *previous* definition of that type prevents its *redefinition*.